# 10k flag handling gone and what you can do about it

Tags: discussion, review, deleted-answers, low-quality-posts

With [Let's get rid of the 10K flag queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue) (MSE), the ability for 10k users to see flags (particularly not an answer and very low quality) is gone.  This means that the little blue box for notifying a 10k user of a not an answer or low quality flag is gone.

What this means is that the only way for 20k users to be notified of discovered bad answers is through the low quality review queue ( https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats ).  Note that a single 'looks good' or 'edit' can kick a question out of the low quality review queue.

I ask that people not use trivial edits on bad answers to remove it from the queue.  If an answer is in there and you fix an 'i' to an 'I' it is removed from the queue and drastically reduced in visibility - but it still isn't a better answer.  Such changes mean it is *more* likely to get deleted by a moderator rather than a 20k user and this complicates the workflow for a user to edit and undelete the answer.

As a 10k user one has the [ability to see the history of *everyone's* activity in a queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184309/165773) and the action took:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6rhA.png]

20k users, please use this ability to double check edit and looks good reviews that have been booted from the queue to see if a delete vote is necessary on them anyways.  Also, please look at the [10k tools deletes page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=last7days) to see if there are delete votes on existing answers that need to be handled.

Moderators (and I dislike telling moderators how to do their job - but I've done so in the past), if booting from a queue removes *your* visibility into these flags... well, you've got everything from have a chat with the user to review bans in your utility belt.  With the 10k flag handling gone we (20k users) have less visibility into to handling the answer deletes and its likely you'll need to do more if nothing else changes.

Comment: FWIW, here are my observations on [how Low Quality queue works at Stack Overflow](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2584/168). Have been using it as lately as today and I have to tell you, watching own flag summary and seeing how bad content you flagged gets deleted literally in few seconds with every browser refresh is... impressive

Comment: I would argue that a trivial edit does the opposite of what you suggest and in fact makes it less likely for a moderator to delete it.  The reason is that most of the NAA flags that end up in the moderator queue come from vigilant users in the review queue.  If people aren't doing reviews and flagging things then we are less likely to get flagged as well.  This of course ignores that we sometimes get auto flags from the community bot on low quality posts as well.

Comment: @maple_shaft its the "more likely" aspect. With the 10k flag queue, a number of answers that got flagged NAA or LQ would garner 20k delete votes - often enough to delete the answer.  With the removal of visibility into the flags, there will be fewer 20k delete votes and *more* diamond delete votes. Users can edit and work to undelete their own deleted answers by 20k users - they can't do it from a mod (and 20ks can't undelete a mod delete).  Thus, the more mod deletes complicates the workflow. Its not that its more likely to get deleted, but more likely to be deleted by a mod.

Comment: On the other hand, if people don't use the 'looks good' or 'edit' to eject a poor answer from the low quality queue (if you didn't improve the quality of the answer, fixing the 'i' to an 'I' doesn't help), the recommend delete and delete votes by the community will make for an easier undelete process.